# Binary search list of derived class for element of base class, using a base class comparer

Tags: c#, casting

I have a base class `CodeElement` like

```
public class CodeElement
{
   public string Name;

   public CodeElement(string name)
   {
      Name = name;
   }

   // ...
}
```

and several derived classes (`Class`, `Window`, `Constant`, etc.) like

```
public class Class : CodeElement
{
   public Class(string name) : base(name)
   {}

   // ...
}
```

Note that the constructor is always like this (except the name, obviously). I also have a class `CodeElementComparer` implementing `IComparer<CodeElement>` which simply compares by `Name`.

My problem is the following: I have one somewhat large list (<10,000 elements) of each derived class on which I need to run a very large number of searches, by name (several million each). The Lists are filled before any searches are run. As such, I sort each List after they are complete (using the `CodeElementComparer`) and then use `List<T>.BinarySearch` like this

```
private Class FindClass(List<Class> classes, string name)
{
   Class dummy = new Class(name);
   int index = classes.BinarySearch(dummy, codeElementComparer);
   if (index >= 0)
   {
      return classes[index];
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Runtime is just fine, the problem is that new derived classes are regularly added, forcing me to copy paste the above method every time. What I am looking for is something like

```
private T FindElement<T>(List<T> elements, string name) where T : CodeElement
{
   CodeElement dummy = new CodeElement(name);
   int index = elements.BinarySearch(dummy, codeElementComparer);
   if (index >= 0)
   {
      return elements[index];
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

However, this does not compile, since `List<T>.BinarySearch` requires `dummy` to be of type `T` (even though I am only using an `IComparer<CodeElement>`). Here's what I considered; unfortunately, I am stuck on each approach:

1. Cast the `List<T>` to `List<CodeElement>`. I know this does not work because Lists are writable and I could theoretically add a `Window` to a `List<Class>` that way. From what I gathered from other questions on here, casting it to `IEnumerable<CodeElement>` works, but `IEnumerable` does not support binary search (since that requires O(1) access to make sense).
2. Create a dummy of type `T`, using the constructor. While **I** know that there will always be a constructor which takes only the name parameter, the compiler does not. If I had a way to specify that all derived classes must have such a constructor, I could make dummy of type `T`.
3. Change the type of the elements parameter to `List<CodeElement>`, then cast the return to `T`. This does compile, but is super unsafe.

Do you have any concise solution to this?
EDIT: Although the names are not unique, handling that once when creating a dictionary is still better than dealing with binary search, as @canton7 pointed out. I am still interested in how to handle this with Lists though.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `Dictionary<string, CodeElement>`? That will give you O(1) lookup rather than O(log n), and you won't have to deal with `List<T>.BinarySearch`

Comment: are the names unique in your example?

Comment: Mostly because I am not sure the names are unique. If there is a duplication, one can be "covered" by another, though in hindsight, handling that at dictionary creation is infinitely faster than dealing with binary search. I am leaving the question open though, because I am genuinely curious how to handle this with Lists.

Comment: Even if you really need binary search you can use a [SortedList<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question (regardless of discussions on whether a better collection type would be better), one way is to make use of [`Span<T>.BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.binarysearch?view=net-6.0), which takes an `IComparable<T>` rather than just a `T`.

For this, you need to get a `Span<T>` from your `List<T>`. This can be done with [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-6.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_CollectionsMarshal_AsSpan__1_System_Collections_Generic_List___0__), but note that this gives you a reference to the underlying array which can change if the list is resized, so use the resulting span with caution!

The final code looks a bit like this:

```
private T FindElement<T>(List<T> elements, string name) where T : CodeElement
{
   CodeElement dummy = new CodeElement(name);
   var span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(elements);
   int index = span.BinarySearch(dummy);
   if (index >= 0)
   {
      return span[index];
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}

class CodeElement : IComparable<CodeElement>
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public CodeElement(string name) => Name = name;
    
    public int CompareTo(CodeElement other) => Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(Name, other?.Name);
}
```

Note that you don't have to use `CodeElement` as your `dummy` -- anything which implements `IComparable<CodeElement>` will do it.

---

That said, note that a binary search is not particularly hard to implement. [Here's `Span<T>.BinarySearch`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/SpanHelpers.BinarySearch.cs,26) and [here's `Array.BinarySearch`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Array.cs,557), and [another random one](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Build.Framework/ArraySortHelper.cs,86). You can avoid the whole `dummy` thing by copying and tweaking one of these implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dummy instance with type `T` using reflection. Here is a sample that I just tested :

```
    private T FindElement<T>(List<T> elements, string name) where T : CodeElement {

        //CodeElement dummy = new CodeElement(name);
        //using System;
        T dummy = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), name);
        int index = elements.BinarySearch(dummy, codeElementComparer);
        if (index >= 0) {
            return elements[index];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```